# How to speed up evaluation of expression (multiple variables) to gain speed? Compile?

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, compile

I obtained some long expression and need to use them with a lot of different parameters inside a simulation. However, evaluation of the expressions is pretty slow, so that I would like to speed it up. The first (and only) thing that came to my mind was `Compile`. But, unfortunately, speed is not improved significantly.

This is an example of the shortest expression (unable to paste the larger ones because they exceed the limits on pastebin):

```
fun[tt_, sig_, time_, expon_, bShift_, lam_] = Uncompress@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/nj83nT2b"];
funComp = Compile[{{tt, _Real}, {sig, _Real}, {time, _Real}, {expon, _Integer}, {bShift, _Real}, {lam, _Real}}, fun[tt, sig, time, expon, bShift, lam]];
fun[3.4, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0836853, 0.045048} *)
funComp[3.4, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0718691, 0.045048} *)
```

As you can see, `Compile` basically has no effect. The bigger issue is that the harmful expressions I am dealing with rather take 10s to evaluate and I'd like to see one or more orders of magnitude speed up (if possible). I hope that the small example here is essentially limited by the same effect as the bigger expressions, so that it serves as a proper toy example.

Background on `fun`: It essentially is composed of sums and products of Gaussians and their derivatives to higher orders (also powers of them).

Is there a way to significantly speed up the evaluation process? Potentially by more advanced usage of `Compile` or some other trick? Currently this is a serious bottleneck in my simulations.

Comment: You haven't generated the expression for the function `fun` by hand, have you? Please give us the code that produces this expression. If it contains many `Sum`: That's great because the `Sum`s can be more efficiently compiled as this humongous symbolic expression. Plus one might use vectorized code instead of `Compile` which may perform even better.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Sorry, with "obtained" I mean from external sources. The derivation does not explicitly contain `Sum` in the sense of using the corresponding MMA function. Indeed, the humongous expression was obtained "by hand" in the form of manually adding/multiplying Gaussians with certain parameters. Was "vectorized code" explicitly referring to a possible solution of `Sum`s were used or is it a general idea?

Comment: Well, vectorization often boils down to vector-vector and matrix-vector products, so many sums can be replace by vectorized code. But also many built-in arithmetic operations are already vectorized (in particular, they have the attribute `Listable`). For example, if `a` is a list of machine-precision real or complex numbers (and a should also be a packed array), `Exp[a]` will be compute _much_ faster than `Exp /@ a` or `Table[ Exp[x],{x,a}]`. And `Total[Exp[a]]` is mush faster than `Sum[Exp[x], {x, a}]`.

Comment: Hm. What is the external source? If it is wirtten in another programming language, maybe its code can be processed to a simple symbolic Mathematica expression (and a list of replacement rules for the constants).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher External source is someone who is working with me. I will get in touch to see if things can be boiled down so that vectorization may be used. But the answer you provide below already helps significantly, so a major step towards bearable evaluation times can be made!

Comment: If the souce is a coworker - perfect. Moreover, I'd like to point out that writing such expressions by hand is very error-prone. Imho, best practice is write code for writing such expressions. And debug the former thouroughly (which should be easier as it is shorter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code for `fun[tt, sig, time, expon, bShift, lam]]` was not correctly inlined into the compiled function `funComp`. Most robust ways is to use `With` as follows. I also apply `N` to avoid some integer to double typecasts that would otherwise take place at runtime.

```
funComp2 = With[{code = N[fun[tt, sig, time, expon, bShift, lam]]},
   Compile[{{tt, _Real}, {sig, _Real}, {time, _Real}, {expon, _Integer}, {bShift, _Real}, {lam, _Real}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
    ]
   ];
```

(Compilation takes longer now because now there happens a lot.)

Resulting timings on my machine:

```
fun[3.4, 10./4, 10., 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2.]] // AbsoluteTiming
funComp[3.4, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.072316, 0.045048}
>
> {0.000197, 0.045048}

PS. You *might* get a further minor performance boost by changing `{expon, _Integer}` to `{expon, _Real}` because there are still some integer to double typecasts left in the C code. But that was hardly measurable with the simple test I tried so far.

PPS. You might probably want to apply this function to large lists of inputs. The the following way to compile the function (with options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True`) might be your friend:

```
funComp3 = With[{code = N[fun[tt, sig, time, expon, bShift, lam]]},
   Compile[{{tt, _Real}, {sig, _Real}, {time, _Real}, {expon, _Real}, {bShift, _Real}, {lam, _Real}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];
```

Here some timing examples.

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100}];

r1 = fun[#, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]] & /@ a; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = fun[a, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r3 = funComp3[#, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]] & /@ a; // RepeatedTiming // First
r4 = funComp3[a, 10/4, 10, 3, 1.3456, Sqrt[2]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
errors = {Max[Abs[r1 - r2]], Max[Abs[r2 - r3]], Max[Abs[r3 - r4]]}
```

> 9.128
>
> 0.151
>
> 0.00040
>
> 0.000047
>
> {2.60209*10^-18, 6.07153*10^-18, 0.}

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you very much for the detailed analysis. It helps _a lot_!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Wow, that's quite an improvment! I am a little bit confused tho which function is which. Is the very first code block supposed to define `funComp`, not `funComp2`? Or the `funComp` is the OP's function, and you have two examples with timing results for two different `funComp2`, as in the 1st and 3rd code sections (they differ by `Listable` and `Parallel`)?

Comment: @kkm Well observed! I corrected that and also replaced `AbsoluteTiming` by `RepeatedTiming`. The latter takes much longer to compute a timing estimate but it is also much more accurate, in particular with very small timings. In order to clarify: The `Parallelization->True` gets only active if (i) the compiled function has also the attribute `Listable` and (ii) the function is also called in the appropriate way: For `r3`, `funComp3` is `Map`ped over the input vector; this does _not_ exploit the `Listable` property while `r4` profits from both listability and (a bit) from parallelization.

Comment: @kkm So the only difference between `r3` and `r4` is the way you call the function. Btw.: Using `funComp2` for `r3` leads to exactly the same timing: The underlying C-codes of `funComp2` and `funComp3` are identical (upto the names of the functions of course).

Comment: It's clear now which is which, thanks! As for the parallel matrix ops, If MMA uses MKL automatic parallelization, then it depends a lot of CPU architecture, problem size, L3 cache, but the most on the present alignment of stars. I've experienced bizarre results with a pure C++ programs, like a VM (Hyper-V) benefitting from parallel computation greatly, being on the order of a few times faster, while its own host physical computer experiencing some *degradation* on the same problem. Same OS, same MKL version, same program and task, and VM computed faster than its host. Black magic ,no less!